# PHP Dynamic ComboBox

Tags: javascript, php, sql

i almost got this, but i need the comboboxes to be dynamic and i cant get it, this is how it looks:

! https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDBOp.jpg

I have this code:

```php
<form action="PostDelPhoto.php" name="delForm" method="post" >

<select name="categoriaMod" id="catMod">
</br>

<?php
    require('bd.php');
    $sql="SELECT * FROM Categorias ORDER BY ID DESC;";
    $queryexec=mysql_query($sql,$conn);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($queryexec)){
        $Categoria =$row["nombre_categoria"];

        echo '<option value="'.$Categoria.'">'.$Categoria.'</option>';     
    };

    echo'</select>';
?>
```

```php
<select name="SelectPhoto" id="SelectPhoto" value="">

<?php
    require('bd.php');
    $sql="SELECT * FROM Paisajes ORDER BY ID DESC;";
    $queryexec=mysql_query($sql,$conn);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($queryexec)){
        $filename =$row["nombre_archivo"];

        echo '<option value="'.$filename.'">'.$filename.'</option>';     
    };

    echo'</select>';
?>
```

In this last php While, I need static "Paisajes" from the SQL Query, to take the value in real time from option combobox after it, but i cant manage to get it.

All ideas are welcome! Thanks!

Comment: You need an ajax call to re-fill thefirst or second combobox according to the selection made in the first or second..

Comment: As Naruto said. This is because php will only run as the page loads and you cannot run it dynamically as you want to, so learn about javascript and AJAX.